# Finding series from its sum, then finding its reciprocal's sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, telescopic-series

If $$\sum_{r=1}^nt_r=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{12}$$, then value of $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{t_r}$$ is

Now, how can we find the series (i.e. formulae of $n^{th}$ term) from the sum?
The answer is $\frac{4n}{n+1}$

Comment: the index is $r$ but you have $t_n$?

Comment: The posted solutions appear to assume that you wanted the initial sum to hold $\forall n$ but of course you don't say that anywhere.  If you are making that assumption, you should make it explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$t_n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{4}-\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{4}=\frac{n(n+1)}{4}.$$
Now, use $$\frac{4}{n(n+1)}=4\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$ and a telescopic summation.

Comment: @Usercomingsoon Thank you for your accepting. Now, show please your attempts, otherwise this topic would be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
t_n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{12}-\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{12}=\frac{n(n+1)}{4}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{1}{t_n}=\frac{4}{n(n+1)}=\frac{4}{n}-\frac{4}{n+1},
$$
and hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{t_k}=\left(\frac{4}{1}-\frac{4}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{4}{2}-\frac{4}{3}\right)+\cdots+
\left(\frac{4}{n-1}-\frac{4}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{4}{n}-\frac{4}{n+1}\right)\\ =\frac{4}{1}-\frac{4}{n+1}=\frac{4n}{n+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The sum and difference are inverse operations:

$\begin{align*}
S_n
  &= \sum_{1 \le k\le n} t_k \\
t_n
  &= S_ n - S_{n - 1}
\end{align*}$

Thus you can get the term $t_n$ knowing the sum, and set up the sum of reciprocals.